# How do I get the current executing directory on linux with .Net Core?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to load in an XML schema file to validate some information on a `.Net Core 2.1` api that is on a linux server.  Unfortunately, I do not have access to this server (we use jenkins to deploy so I have 0 contact with it), so I can only test on my computer which is Windows 10.
I have tried the following:

```
System.AppContext.BaseDirectory
System.AppContext.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppContext.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("bin"));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
GetType().Assembly.Location
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

All of these return the current execution location on Windows (i.e. `C:/SomePath/SomeProject/Name/api.dll`) which I can use with `Path.Combine` to produce the path to the schema file.

However, on linux, these all return `/home/app/` which is not where the dll should be according to the Jenkins logs.  This is leading to failures loading the schema file.  The project is actually located under `/services/projectname/`.

Test Code:

```
var schema = new XmlSchemaSet { XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver() };
schema.Add(null, Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Schema/schema.xsd"));
```

Expected: On Windows and Linux this loads the schema file using the .dll execution path as the base.

Actual: On Linux I get `home/app` instead of the correct path.

Edit: I cannot hardcode the path.  The path changes on every deployment as the project name is versioned.  This means the second I deploy it, any hardcoded value will be incorrect.  I absolutely require a relative path.  Beyond that technical requirement, hard coding is a major taboo.  I will never get it past a code review.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question earlier today?

Comment: Found this by searching your title: `AppContext.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppContext.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("bin"));`

Comment: @Symon I'll try that, but `AppContext.BaseDirectory` on linux gives me `home/app` every time.  The project is located under `/services` off root so I don't know how that will help.  Keep in mind, that could change, I absolutely cannot hardcode this for obvious reasons.

Comment: As I feared, same issue @Symon thank you for trying though.

Comment: My two cents. Use the absolute path if you know it. Load the XML from "/services/projectname/...", why try to be relative? Second thing, don't use "\\" backward slashes on POSIX but a single "/", such as "Schema/schema.xsd".

Comment: Because if it moves paths, which can happen, it won't work anymore.  I need to use relative because things change on docker containers.  

Alright, I'll change the slashes. @pid

Comment: Yeah I did @stuartd but it contained incorrect information.  I decided to delete it and reword the question without the incorrect information in the hope that the same eyes that overlooked it due to incorrect info would give it another glance.

Comment: @SusannahPotts did you get a solution for this and if so would you mind providing it

Answer (score 3):

For me, in dotnet core 3.1 the following statement works for a console application in both Windows and Ubuntu:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```